# mod_rewrite for any number of variables

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am a newbie to mod_rewrite and I was wondering if there is any way you could make on rewrite script that handles and number of variables you throw at it.

Example:
`www.krisnicolaou.com/index.php?id=5&sort=asc&limit=25&param=first_name`

to
`www.krisnicolaou.com/5/asc/25/first_name`

...but, you can also pass these variables in on another page and it would work with that one script:
`www.krisnicolaou.com/index.php?page=view&action=add`

to
`www.krisnicolaou.com/view/add/`

I essentially don't want to be limited as to how many parameters I can add on to the end and not have to constantly modify the .htaccess file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want that requested URLs of the first form (`/index.php?page=view&action=add`) are externally redirected to the second form (`/view/add/`)? Or do you rather want the reverse direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117931/apache-modrewrite-one-rule-for-any-number-of-possibilities/119306#119306).

Comment: Torez and great_llama, so one of you linked to it, and the other accepted the link as the answer but neither of you thought the original answer was worth an upvote?  Where's the love?

Answer (score 1):

Usually one want to take 'clean' urls, and covert them to parameters.  What you are asking for is the opposite.  Here's a **tested** ruleset.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=]*)=([^&]*)(&.*)?
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?([^/]+) $1%2/$2?%3 [L]
```

This will run if there are parameters, and for each param, it will add it to the URL and remove it from the param list.  The [N] will cause it to run until there are no more parameters.

To test, I create the following structure:

```
view
view/add
view/add/index.htm
```

I put the above rules in a .htaccess file.

Normal test:
http://www.theeggeadventure.com/2009/index.htm?page=view&action=add

Additional params (404) test
http://www.theeggeadventure.com/2009/index.htm?page=view&action=add&foo=bar
URL /2009/view/add/bar/index.htm was not found on this server.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response but for some reason its not working. Any idea why?  And don't say "did you turn on the rewrite engine" :)

Thanks