# General RewriteRule for many undefined parameters in URL

Tags: url, .htaccess, parameters, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a rule to make that one can generalize, since multiple pages to pass the values are different. Right now I could do:

```
RewriteRule ^forum/([^/]{1,255})/([\+]{1})/((([a-z]+)([_]{1})([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([/]?))+)$   forum.php?name=$1&$5=$7 [L]
```

To address such as:

```
Nome+del+Forum/+/page_1/action_do
```

Should return:

```
forum.php?name=Nome+del+Forum&page=1&action=do
```

Instead, take only the last parameter (in this case ***action=do***):

```
forum.php?name=Nome+del+Forum&action=do
```

How can I fix? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is if you can put a [`RewriteMap prg:foo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) in the site configuration.  Note that you can't use `RewriteMap` in a `.htaccess` as far as I know.

If you have access to the server configuration file, add something like this, either globally or in your `<VirtualHost>`:

```
RewriteMap forum prg:/path/to/forum-rewriter.pl
```

Then in your chosen `.htaccess` try:

```
RewriteRule ^forum/.* ${forum:$0} [QSA]
```

(In your attempted `RewriteRule` it looked like you wanted to match on paths that start with `forum/` so that's what I'm doing here.)

Next you need to make `forum-rewriter.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;


$| = 1;
while ($_ = <STDIN>) {
    chomp($_);
    if (s,^forum/([^/]+)(/\+)?(/.*)?,forum.php?name=$1, && $3) {
        my $query_string = $3;
        $query_string =~ s,/([^/_]+)_([^/_]+),&$1=$2,g;
        $_ .= $query_string;
    }
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Make sure to `chmod 755 /path/to/forum-rewriter.pl`.

The `RewriteMap` will cause Apache to start `forum-rewriter.pl` once for every httpd process at start time.  Every time the `RewriteRule`'s pattern matches, it'll write the path to the stdin of `forum-rewriter.pl`.  `forum-rewriter.pl` will do its work (if any) on the URL and print the result back to Apache.

FYI it's very easy to test `forum-rewriter.pl`.  Just run it and start sending it paths:

```
$ /tmp/forum-rewriter.pl
forum/Nome+del+Forum/+/page_1/action_do
forum.php?name=Nome+del+Forum&page=1&action=do
forum/Nome+del+Forum/page_1/action_do
forum.php?name=Nome+del+Forum&page=1&action=do
forum/Nome+del+Forum
forum.php?name=Nome+del+Forum
foo
foo
```

If you can't use `RewriteMap`, I guess it's possible with `mod_rewrite` **but I think this is dangerous**:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:SetForumName} =""
RewriteRule ^forum/([^/]+)(/\+)?(/.*)? /forum.php$3?name=$1 [QSA,E=SetForumName:1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:SetForumName} !=""
RewriteRule ^forum.php/([^/_]+)_([^/_]+)(/.*)? /forum.php$3?$1=$2 [N,QSA]
```

It's dangerous because that `[N]` causes Apache to restart processing all rewrite rules when that second `RewriteRule` matches.  If you're not careful you'll create an infinite loop and Apache will either 500 the request or croak.  Also note the side-effect that it sets the `SetForumName` environment variable.  However, this is the only way I could find to tell mod_rewrite "replace *all* `foo_bar` in the path with `foo=bar` in the query string."

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117931/apache-modrewrite-one-rule-for-any-number-of-possibilities/119306#119306)?

And see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867373/recursive-mod-rewrite-for-search-engine-friendly-urls/1868818#1868818) for some additional info.

The basic info is these rules

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*/)([^/]+)/([^/]+) $1?$2=$3&%1 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/ $1?%1 [L]
```

will rewrite the following

```
/mypage/param1/val1/param2/val2/param3/val3/...     --->
/mypage?param1=val1&param2=val2&param3=val3&...
```

It takes the first parameter and calls that page.  The rest of the parameters are turned into the query string.

EDIT with more about how the code works.

The first line (and the third) merely capture everything after the "?" so that it can be added back to the end of the rewritten URL.  The same thing
can be accomplished with the [QSA] flag, but I prefer to do it
explicitly so it's visible.

The string is saved in the %1 variable.

The second line uses a regular expression to split the URL into three parts.

$2 and $3 are the last two parts of the path.
$1 is everything before that.

So this:

```
/mypage/param1/val1/param2/val2/param3/val3/param4/val4/param5/val5/
```

Becomes this:

```
$1                                                        $2      $3
/mypage/param1/val1/param2/val2/param3/val3/param4/val4/  param5  val5
```

and is rewritten as this (spaces added for readability):

```
/mypage/param1/val1/param2/val2/param3/val3/param4/val4/ ? param5 = val5
```

If your URL uses separators other than slashes, you can modify the regular
expression accordingly.

The [L] ("last") flag prevents the rest of the rules from running.
HOWEVER -- and this is the key -- mod_rewrite calls the webserver with the new
URL and the new URL is sent through mod_rewrite again! This is sometimes called mod_rewrite recursion and is exactly what you want for this to work.

The next time through, the next two parts are stripped off the end and added
to the query string.

This:

```
$1                                           $2      $3     %1
/mypage/param1/val1/param2/val2/param3/val3  param4  val4 ? param5=val5
```

Becomes this:

```
/mypage/param1/val1/param2/val2/param3/val3 ? param4 = val4 & param5=val5
```

This keeps on happening until all the parts of the URL are converted into
parts of the query string.  When that happens, the second line doesn't match
but the fourth line does.  That is what gives you your final URL to call the
program you want.  The links above show answers to slightly different variations
that allow for different rules for that.

Also note that there are limits to the number of times mod_rewrite
can recurse.  See the settings for
`MaxRedirects` in .htaccess and 
`LimitInternalRecursion`
in your apache conf file.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not understand! I don't want the full code, but understand how the code.
The page will always be forum and values are not separated by a slash, but a "_" or ":". With this code:

<pre><code> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
 RewriteRule ^forum/([^/]{1,255})/([^/]+)([:]{1})([^/]+)
 viewforum.php?name=$1&$2=$4&%3 [L]
</code></pre>

It works in half, taking only the first parameter.
Thanks!

Comment: FedericoBiccheddu, I added more of an explanation. I hope this helps. I know your URL uses `_` and not `/` but the concept should work just as well if you use a slightly different regex.