# mod_rewrite for dynamically mapping SEO friendly links directly to individual files, without routing via front controller

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm looking for an SEO friendly url rewrite rule that would work for any common PHP site that doesn't have a front controller. It would map the SEO friendly url directly to the PHP file that is found to exist on the server and convert the remaining URL branches to standard URL parameters.

For example:

***/folder1/folder2/folder3/page/var1/val1/var2/val2/var3/val3***

would map to:

***/folder1/folder2/folder3/page.php?var1=val1&var2=val2&var3=val3***

Now, here's the tricky part. Since the rewrite rules need to be completely agnostic to all the names of folders, pages, and variables, it would need to base the rewrite of the URL parameters on the exact location along link where can be found a file that exists along the path. For instance, consider if the following file happened to exist (hypothetically) off the document root: ***/folder1/folder2.php***
In this case, the following remapping would be legitimate and acceptable:
***/folder1/folder2.php?folder3=page&var1=val1&var2=val2&var3=val3***

This would be the ultimate rewrite rule for many traditional websites that have already been built that want their URLs and parameters to instantly become URL-friendly.

The only examples that I have found involve mapping everything to work with a single front controller or otherwise hard-coded files in the rule that are expected to exist rather than have mod_rewrite detect their existence dynamically. They're related, but not flexible for any file that is found to exist:

- http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=363420
- [apache mod_rewrite one rule for any number of possibilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117931/apache-modrewrite-one-rule-for-any-number-of-possibilities)
- [Recursive mod_rewrite for search engine friendly urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867373/recursive-mod-rewrite-for-search-engine-friendly-urls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache web server does already know such a concept:

- [MultiViews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews):

  > The effect of `MultiViews` is as follows: if the server receives a request for `/some/dir/foo`, if `/some/dir` has `MultiViews` enabled, and `/some/dir/foo` does not exist, then the server reads the directory looking for files named foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then chooses the best match to the client's requirements.
- [Path Info](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo):

  > This directive controls whether requests that contain trailing pathname information that follows an actual filename (or non-existent file in an existing directory) will be accepted or rejected. The trailing pathname information can be made available to scripts in the `PATH_INFO` environment variable.
  >
  > For example, assume the location `/test/` points to a directory that contains only the single file `here.html`. Then requests for `/test/here.html/more` and `/test/nothere.html/more` both collect `/more` as `PATH_INFO`.

All you then need to adjust is to take the path info part and parse it.

Besides that, if you really want to implement that behavior with mod_rewrite, try this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /$1?$2=$3 [N,QSA]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0.php -f
RewriteRule .+ /$0.php [L]
```

Comment: This slowly grinds my entire system to a halt. I had to hard reboot twice. :D Here is what I did: I placed that mod_rewrite in my .htaccess file and created a directory structure /docroot/folder1/folder2/folder3/page.php, then I tried accessing it with localhost.test.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/page/var1/val1/var2/val2/var3/val3 and that is when my system begins to crash.

Comment: I tried another approach by accessing the following: localhost.test.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/page which seems to refresh my browser and places this into the URL bar: http://localhost.test.com/folder1/folder2/?folder3=page.php -- some additional adjustment needed maybe?

Comment: @DavidPesta: The *N* flag is to be used with caution as it doesn’t increment the internal recursion counter and thus can cause an infinite recursion. But it seems that you’re using some additional rules that might interfere with these.

Comment: I ended up directing everything to a front controller to route destinations via PHP. Thanks for the help though.