# htaccess multi parameter detection

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

First of all sorry for my bad english, I hope you'll understand me.

I'd like to use one `RewriteRule` to detect multiple url area (eg.: foo/bar/more/read/)

The regexp for this is very simple: `([^\/]*\/?)`, but I can use this as one parameter.

Have you any idea, how I can give the params like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\/]*\/?)$ index.php?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are look for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117931/apache-mod-rewrite-one-rule-for-any-number-of-possibilities/119306#119306), to process *n* number of parameters?

Alternatively you could just send everything to index.php with:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA]
```

...and split the querystring in php. There is something to be said for simplicity...

Comment: Hey Vrac, i tought about your second idee and if i dont find an other way i'll do this... but the link look like what i mean :) THANKS <3