# url rewrite for N number of querystring

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

I am in need of a URL rewrite to `http://jzbeta.local/category.php?u=new-page&limit=all&page=2&style=new` as below,

`http://jzbeta.local/new-page&limit=all&page=2&style=new`

So far my htaccess file has the following rule:

`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\/?$ /category.php?u=$1 [NC]`

Where I can use only one query string.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
Once i changed existing rewrite as following, it worked as i expected.
`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\/?$ /category.php?u=$1 **[L,QSA]**`

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /category.php?u=$1&limit=$2&page=$3&style=$4 [NC,L]
```

Comment: yea it is possible. but if i need to use **N** number of querystring variables what would be the best possible option?

Comment: This has come up before, see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/117931/apache-mod-rewrite-one-rule-for-any-number-of-possibilities/119306#119306)