# mod_rewrite rules for different and optional parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am writing a news program with php and need help in writing mod_rewrite rules for it. Although i have some idea about mod_rewrite and regex but not much. What i am trying to do is map

```
#if all 5 params matches   
index.php?cat=uttarakhand&sub_cat=dehradun&genre=business&news_id=1&slug=my-news to /uttarakhand/dehradun/business/1/my-news
#if 3 prams match
index.php?cat=uttarakhand&sub_cat=dehradun&genre=business to /uttarakhand/dehradun/business
#if 2 prams match
index.php?cat=uttarakhand&sub_cat=dehradun to /uttarakhand/dehradun
#if 1 prams match
index.php?cat=uttarakhand to /uttarakhand
```

All above can be achievable that i know but the problem start after this, lets say if cat and genre is the parameters it should be

```
    #if cat and genre matches
    index.php?cat=uttarakhand&genre=business to /uttarakhand/business
    #if sub_cat and genre matches
    index.php?sub_cat=dehradun&genre=business to /dehradun/business
    #if only genre matches
    index.php?genre=business to /business
    #if only news matches
    index.php?news_id=1&slug=my-news to /1/my-news
```

I don't know if it is even possible but the idea is if some of the parameters are missing even than mod_rewrite should redirect to matching query for php to process.
I have been searching stackoverflow for this for quite some days but i didn't find similar problem and its solution for me to use in my perspective.

Comment: Do you want a rewire so the user enter `/uttarakhand/dehradun` and this will be rewritten to `index.php?cat=uttarakhand&sub_cat=dehradun` internally or do you want a redirect so user enters `index.php?cat=uttarakhand&sub_cat=dehradun` and the URL change in the browser to `/uttarakhand/dehradun`

Comment: Yes the first one user will enter/uttarakhand/dehradun and php will process index.php?cat=uttarakhand&sub_cat=dehradun and so in for all

Answer (score 0):

The first part is possible but not the secound.

How should htaccess know if you have e.g `/foo/bar` if `foo` is a `cat` or `sub_cut`... this is something you only can do in your PHP logic

So what we can do it only something like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# rewite for /cat
RewriteRule ^([^/])/?$ /index.php?cat=%1 [L]

# rewite for /cat/sub_cat
RewriteRule ^([^/])/([^/])/?$ /index.php?cat=%1&sub_cat=%2 [L]

# rewite for /cat/sub_cat/genre
RewriteRule ^([^/])/([^/])/([^/])/?$ /index.php?cat=%1&sub_cat=%2&genre=%3 [L]

# rewite for /cat/sub_cat/genre/news_id/slug
RewriteRule ^([^/])/([^/])/([^/])/([^/])/([^/])/?$ /index.php?cat=%1&sub_cat=%2&genre=%3&news_id=%4&slug=%5 [L]
```

#### Edit:

If you have an extra `/`in your URL like e.g. `//sub_cat/genre` this should be rewritten to `/index.php?cat=&sub_cat=sub_cat&genre=genre`. `cat` will be present in your `$_GET` variable but is empty.

#### Adendum:

Personally I do not think that you should do this in htaccess at all. The logic is to complex that you should build it in htaccess. I would just rewritte the complete string to your index.php file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```

Now you have the complete URL in one variable, and from there you can build up you logic. This is what most CMS or PHP Frameworks do, for a good reason.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know first part is doable but I am more looking into the second part, if that's not at all  can be achieved than what should my url structure should be for clean url which can gracefully handle those request for the second part of my question?

Comment: Is the update possible for you? or the Keyword in some way limited e.g. only 'business' or ' private' can be sub_cat. If both is not the case than only htaccees is not the solution for you

Comment: Yes updates are  absolutely possible, since I am coding the backend right now, but categories are dynamic subcategories are dynamic and genre will define the nature of news and still dynamic, so can not fix any of those, although I was thinking if it's possible, url structure could be cat/sub_cat/genre/business, So I could use cat/genre/businesses or sub_cat/genre/business

Comment: See my Adendum, I dont belive that htaccess is a good solution for you at all.

Comment: Okay, I got your point but php logic could lead to some kind of security threat, I haven't dig any cms/framework logic yet for this, if it's possible could you provide one example?

Comment: I was checking this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117931/apache-modrewrite-one-rule-for-any-number-of-possibilities/119306#119306 if it's possible for any number of queries, my question might have a similar answer, still waiting, if nothing comes up I will accept yours and up vote. And yes I do really appreciate your work and helping nature.

Comment: Yes you cloud do this, but than you have to change the URL like this `/cat/uttarakhand/subcat/dehradun/genre/business/newsid/1/slug/my-news`  and I don't believe that this is what you want.

Comment: BTW: you can also up vote if you like a answer of find it usefully, even it its not the accepted one, no mater if its your question or the question from someone else ;-) Appreciate a question can only be done by the person you asked the question, and should be done if you got a answer, sometimes this also means that the answer is:  "its not possible the way you want to do it"